# link for picture outside var/www/ folder? (linux, php)

Tags: php, linux

I have a small linux server at home with a usbstick in it. After I mounted the stick I want to make a link to a .png file in the /media/usb/ directory. So if I click on it I can see the picture of the usbstick.

But if i do this:

```
<a href="/media/usb/picture.png"> picture </a>
```

I get 404 Not found error. I think it just search through the /var/www/ folder and not on the whole server. I heard that something about alias or so. Is that the thing what I need?

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: you can create a symlink to `/media/usb/`. For example `ln -s /media/usb /var/www/usb/` and then you link the images like `a href="/usb/picture.png"`

Comment: Make sure your permissions are correct on the source too, the apache user needs to be able to read it.

Comment: OK adding it as an answer so that it is clear that the problem is solved : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see my comment was useful to you, let me post it as an answer so that it is clear:

You can create a symlink to `/media/usb/`. For example with:

```
ln -s /media/usb /var/www/usb/
```

Then you link the images like

```
<a href="/usb/picture.png"> picture </a>
```